# Decide what frame to trigger according to an option select

Tags: javascript, html

I have a web page that contains a select field and a submit button. The field contains two values like `a` and `b`. So what I want to do is to take values from the current page and display it in frame `x` if I select value `a` from the select field or display the values from current page to frame `y` if I select value `b`. 
I was thinking to something in the page frame like:

```
<form name="current" method="post" onsubmit="myfunction()">
```

And write a JavaScript function like this:

```
  function myfunction()
    {
       var c=document.forms["current"]["select_name"].value;

       if (c=="a" ){
         Then do something like: 
<form name="myForm1" target="content" action="x.html" method="post" >
       } else {
          then do something like
<form name="myForm2" target="content" action="y.html" method="post" > 
       }
    }
```

In this case if I select value `a` then I will do `method="post"` to the x.html or if I select value `b` then do `method="post"` to the y.html.

Thanks...

Comment: What do you mean by `trigger`?

Comment: Give the frames `id`s, have the value of the select be said `id`, use `document.getElementById(document.forms[...].value)`. That's... basically what the `id`s are for, unless for some reason you need the values in the `<select>` to be different than the frame `id`s. In that case just use an object as a dictionary between values and frame ids: `var frameNames = {'a': 'x', 'b': 'y'}; document.getElementById(frameNames[document.forms[...].value]);`

Comment: @tymeJV I mean by trigger is to display some contents of current page to either x frame or y frame according to the selection

Comment: @user1762447 Sounds more like you need plain old DHTML than frames. That said, it's really unclear what you're asking - as in, which part of the code do you expect us to fill in?

Comment: @tymeJV I edited my question, I hope I clarified what I want... and thanks a lot for your comments.